# authentication token issue EVE

Tags: python, eve

Hi I am using the eve token authentication (http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html#accounts-with-token-authentication) but am stuck with a 401 message.

---

```
class RolesAuth(TokenAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token,  allowed_roles, resource, method):
        users = app.data.driver.db['users']
        lookup = {'token': token}
        if allowed_roles:
            lookup['roles'] = {'$in': allowed_roles}
        user = users.find_one(lookup)
        return user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Eve(auth=RolesAuth)
    app.run()
```

---

I am using username test and password 1234 > this results in base64 encoded; dGVzdDoxMjM0

When I use cURL

---

```
curl -X "GET" "http://api.domain.com:5000/people/obama" -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdDoxMjM0"
```

this is resulting in the 401

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_error": {"message": "Please provide proper credentials", "code": 401}}
```

---

I checked mongodb and the token is there

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551004d6714e7a5fec0729e3"),
    "username" : "test",
    "_updated" : ISODate("2015-03-23T12:19:34.000Z"),
    "roles" : [ 
        "admin", 
        "superuser"
    ],
    "token" : "dGVzdDoxMjM0",
    "_created" : ISODate("2015-03-23T12:19:34.000Z"),
    "password" : "1234",
    "_etag" : "96b41717630a49bca41b89f971cc3b8bd8d518a3"
}
```

---

Is there something wrong with the cURL command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a few things wrong with your code:

1. You are sending username and password with you Authorization header while your `RolesAuth` class is performing lookups on `token`. Try passing an encoded token instead.
2. You stored the base64 encoded token in Mongo but you probably want to store the  clean token instead, as the `check_auth` method will receive a decoded value as `token` argument (or you have to encode it again before performing the lookup).
3. You really really don't want to store the clean password in the database. These should be hashed/salted.

Comment: Point 1. OK thanks, I was under the impression that the basic auth username and password became the token in the authorization header. So now I add and send the Authorization header with the token encoded like
curl -X "GET" "http://api.domain.com:5000/people/obama" -H "Authorization: bGVvdG9rZW4=" in which  Authorization: bGVvdG9rZW4= is Authorization: + base64 encode <tokenstring> however I am still getting a 401
 
Point 2. Correct thanks changed it

Point 3. Correct, was for testing purpose, will be removed after test

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode in base64 you token before send it and in mongodb not encoded.

When Eve recived the token its decoded and then compare it with the db.

if you send:

```
curl -X "GET" "http://api.domain.com:5000/people/obama" -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdDoxMjM0"
```

In the db has to be stored:

```
"token" : "1234",
```

Moreover you have to encoded token + : For example if your token value in db is "1234" you have to encode and send "1234:"

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more. Why should this be done? Maybe you could even link a source to your answer.